# jquery change class of a span inside a button on click

Tags: jquery, html, toggleclass

I have a button as follows and I want to change the class name of span on it. But the following code is not working. How can I do that?

```
<button id="btn_new">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>new
</button>
```

jquery code:

```
$('#btn_new').click(function({
   $(this).find('span').toggleClass('ui-icon-plus ui-icon-tick');
});
```

also i tried this:

```
$('#btn_new').click(function({
   $(this).find('span').removeClass('ui-icon-plus').addClass('ui-icon-tick');
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well you can try removeClass and addClass like this

```
$('#btn_new').click(function({ 
      $(this).find('span').removeClass('ui-icon-plus');
      $(this).find('span').addClass('ui-icon-tick');
});
```

Comment: if we have multiple buttons with same class names how we can only change class name of span that is clicked without affecting other buttons ?

Answer (score 3):

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/renL0z0r/)

```
$('#btn_new').click(function(){

   $(this).find('span').toggleClass('ui-icon-plus ui-icon-tick');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btn_new').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();   
   var caption=$.trim($(this).text());
   var icon=$(this).find('span');
   if(caption == 'new'){ 
    $(this).text('save'); 
    icon.toggleClass('ui-icon-plus ui-icon-check'); 
   } 
});
```

Comment: why its not working like this?     $("#btn_new").click(function(e){
           var caption=$(this).text();
           var icon=$(this).find('span');
           e.preventDefault();
           if(caption == 'new'){
               $(this).text('save');
               icon.toggleClass('ui-icon-plus ui-icon-check');
          }
    });

Comment: var caption=$(this).val();

Comment: use .val() for button

Comment: Answers that consist of code only without additional explaination are not very useful to future visitors. Consider adding explaination to your Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to close bracket in click event.  `function()`

```
$('#btn_new').click(function(){ //Here
   $(this).find('span').toggleClass('ui-icon-plus ui-icon-tick');
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qL659gmh/2/)**

Comment: hi - no its the typing mistak

Comment: @sasanmohammadi Here you can check in fiddle it's working. class is changed for span

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btn_new').click(function(){
   $(this).find('span').toggleClass('ui-icon-plus').toggleClass('ui-icon-tick');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn_new').click(function(){
    $(this).find('span').toggleClass('ui-icon-plus ui-icon-tick');
    });
});
```

also please don't forget to add

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

if not added

Answer (score 0):

I tried here but with different class

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn_new").click(function(){
   $(this).find('span').toggleClass('main');
});
});
</script>
<style>
.main {
    font-size: 120%;
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" id="btn_new">
<span class="main">new</span>
</button>

</body>
</html>
```

And its working

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$('#btn_new').click(function(){
  $(this).find('span').toggleClass('ui-icon-plus ui-icon-tick');
});
```

Comment: Code without explaination is often not very useful to future users.

Answer (score 0):

thank you evrey one:
its working . my mistake was that i changed the button text and when span was inside the button, my code remove span and add new text on it. i put another span and now its working.

my html:

```
 <button id="btn_new"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span><span>new</span></button>
```

my jquery:

```
$('#btn_new").click(function(){
   var caption=$(this).find('span:last').text();
   if(caption =='new'){
      $(this+'span:last').text('save');
      $(this+'span:first').toggleClass('ui-icon-plus ui-icon-tick');
   }
}
```